# Finding cubic and quintic residues $\mod31$ quickly

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve $a^3+b^5 = 7^{7^{7^7}}$.

I have proven that $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 19\mod31$ using Fermat-Euler Theorem. A previous answer on this site asserts that $19$ is not equivalent to the sum of a cube and fifth power $\mod31$. Is there a better way to prove that than to just list the cubic and quintic residues? I'm afraid that's all I've come up with and it's quite tedious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily all that tedious. Since $31$ is prime, the multiplicative group module $31$ is cyclic of order $30$, so if you can find a generator $g$ for it, the cubes are exactly the ten powers of $g^3$, and the fifth powers are exactly the six powers of $g^5$.

So all you need to do is to compute a list of the cubes, and then check that $19-g^{5n}$ is not among them for $0\le n\le 5$.

You only need to actually multiply out half of the cubes and fifth powers, because then the rest are minus the ones you've already found. (That is, $g^{15}=-1$).

Comment: Ahh I did use that method - clearly I don't have enough patience whoops. This was a non-calculator question though, which I why I asked if I'd missed a fancier technique. Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: By brute force, $12$ and $19$ are the only numbers that cannot be written $a^3 + b^5$ modulo 31.